# Charts / text boxes in Word not appearing properly when saving as PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, charts

I have a Word document (Office 2007) that I'd like to save as a PDF. Most of the document saves perfectly, but some pie charts and text boxes are not appearing correctly in the PDF. They don't appear at all, or are just basically shadows without color.

Everything looks fine in Print Preview. Also, I have "Print drawing created in Word" selected.

Any ideas?

Thank you.